# How can we skip the some records through SOQL

Tags: soql, salesforcedx, migration-tool, jitterbit

I am retrieving attachments through jitter bit SOQL query, but my all records are not retrieving through in the bulk so I have set the limit of 1000 but when I have download next 1000 records how can I skip first 1000 records from the SOQL query, I have tried OFFSET but it is giving the result only 1 record . Can you please help in this.

**SOQL Query:**

```
SELECT Id, Body, BodyLength, ConnectionReceivedId, ConnectionSentId, ContentType, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Description, IsDeleted, IsPartnerShared, IsPrivate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, Name, OwnerId, ParentId, SystemModstamp FROM Attachment order by Id limit 1000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDs are numbers actually, so you can use the last selected ID in the next query. I mean, If you make a query `SELECT Id FROM Attachment ORDER BY Id LIMIT 2` and it returns something like `{a00J000000BWNYk, a00J000000BWNYl}`. You can take the last ID and use it to found the next two Attachments, `SELECT Id FROM Attachment WHERE Id > 'a00J000000BWNYl' ORDER BY Id LIMIT 2`.

Hope it works!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id, Body, BodyLength, ConnectionReceivedId, ConnectionSentId, ContentType, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Description, IsDeleted, IsPartnerShared, IsPrivate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, Name, OwnerId, ParentId, SystemModstamp FROM Attachment ORDER BY Id LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000
```

The result set for the preceding example would be a subset of the full result set, returning rows 1001 through 2000 of the full set.

check it out for more information

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm

Comment: I have already try this but when I am using the offset in this query it giving the result only one record

Comment: I tried this at my end and it is working perfectly